# Clicar no texto do label, fazê-lo aparecer no input e editar esse label

Tags: javascript, html, crud, label

Sou novo em JavaScript e estou com um dilema. Eu consigo adicionar o conteúdo de um input text em um label, mas eu preciso fazer o conteúdo do label aparecer no input do tipo text mencionado, clicar no botão editar e mudar o conteúdo do label.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
     var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
        var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
  var capturando = "";
  
  capturando = document.getElementById('valor').value;
  
  var x = 1;
        var label_topico = ("<h3><label class=\"li_001\"> " + capturando + " </label></h3>");
        var textarea_topico = ("<textarea class=\"input_text_001\" /></textarea>");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
  
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
  // acrescenta o label
        fieldWrapper.append(label_topico);
  // acrescenta o textarea
        fieldWrapper.append(textarea_topico);
  // acrescenta o botão remover
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
  // acrescenta o bloco div com o label, textarea e o botão remover
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
  // limpa a caixa de texto
  document.getElementById("valor").value = "";
    });
    $("#edit").click(function() {
 document.getElementById("valor").value = "";
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="buildyourform">
 <input type="text" id="valor" class="input_text_001">
 <input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Edit a field" class="edit" id="edit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `event handler` para capturar um clique nas labels pela classe `.li_001` (classe das labels) adicionando o texto da label clicada no `input#valor` e atribuindo a label clicada numa variável declarada antes sem nenhum valor:

```
var editando;
$(document).on("click", ".li_001", function(){
   $("#valor").val($(this).text().trim());
   editando = $(this);
});
```

No `$("#add").click(function() {` remova o valor da variável `editando`, pois quando você adicionar um novo elemento significa que não é mais uma edição:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
   editando = null;
   // resto do código
```

No `$("#edit").click(function() {` insira um `if` verificando se a variável `editando` possui valor, significando que alguma label está sendo editada, e também após a edição, esvaziar a variável `editando`:

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
   if(editando){
      editando.text($("#valor").val());
      editando = null;
   }
   document.getElementById("valor").value = "";
});
```

Isso é tudo. Veja funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
   var editando;
   $(document).on("click", ".li_001", function(){
      $("#valor").val($(this).text().trim());
      editando = $(this);
   });
   
    $("#add").click(function() {
       editando = null;
     var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
        var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
  var capturando = "";
  
  capturando = document.getElementById('valor').value;
  
  var x = 1;
        var label_topico = ("<h3><label class=\"li_001\"> " + capturando + " </label></h3>");
        var textarea_topico = ("<textarea class=\"input_text_001\" /></textarea>");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
  
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
  // acrescenta o label
        fieldWrapper.append(label_topico);
  // acrescenta o textarea
        fieldWrapper.append(textarea_topico);
  // acrescenta o botão remover
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
  // acrescenta o bloco div com o label, textarea e o botão remover
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
  // limpa a caixa de texto
  document.getElementById("valor").value = "";
    });
      $("#edit").click(function() {
         if(editando){
            editando.text($("#valor").val());
            editando = null;
            document.getElementById("valor").value = "";
         }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buildyourform">
   <input type="text" id="valor" class="input_text_001">
   <input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
   <input type="button" value="Edit a field" class="edit" id="edit" />
</div>
```